# Jenkins installation and test report generation

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, testng

I am using Jmeter and TestNG for Automation testing, I have to move ahead and use the jenkins plug in to generate the report, I am getting test result and test report folders, in the test result folders individual test case result is been stored and in test report,

```
 #cd reports/
    reports_2015-10-13_15-36-11
    #cd reports_2015-10-13_15-36-11

    html

    #cd html
    #ls -ltr 
   total 0
```

Nothing is there, 1st I need to install the jenkins I am running with java version,

```
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

Please suggest me to how to install jenkins and where to get and later how to use it for report generation.

Answer (score 0):

For installing Jenkins you can tryout the following step by step tutorial.

[installing-configuring-and-executing-jobs-with-jenkins-part-1](https://debugger89.wordpress.com/2015/06/12/installing-configuring-and-executing-jobs-with-jenkins-part-1/)